# I try post string request but its not working my code

Tags: ios, swift

ı try to send string request but its not work

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let parameters = "{\"Language\": \"tr\",\"ProcessType\": 1,\"Username\": \"\(self.mailTextField.text ?? "")\",\"Password\": \"\(self.passwordTextField.text ?? "")\"}"
    print(parameters)
    let enUrlParams = try! parameters.aesEncrypt(key: LoginConstants.xApiKey, iv: LoginConstants.IV)
    print(enUrlParams)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpBody = enUrlParams.data(using: .utf8)
```

Output:

{"Language": "tr","ProcessType": 1,"Username": "","Password": ""}

l+Au1MhqAlHr+wDR9UmdjN4IL5XHVnwMJx3rHF/P1MT+aO5Q5YF25f5OJRwDVzXEWu47ocqMxcUqw1onYBya9VCEvqjNQ0FpNCxtPp9fh+Y=

Optional(108 bytes)

statusCode should be 200, but is 500
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000e36e00> { URL: "my url" } { Status Code: 500, Headers {
Date =     (
"Wed, 14 Sep 2022 11:54:35 GMT"
);
Server =     (
"Microsoft-IIS/10.0"
);
"Transfer-Encoding" =     (
Identity
);
"X-Powered-By" =     (
"ASP.NET"
);
} })
responseString = Optional("")

Comment: It's missing the `task` part, and is there an output of the completion? What calls that method?

Comment: Are you getting a 500 response because the username and password are blank?

Comment: its not because ı write correct mail and password after that ı got same error

Comment: You are getting a HTTP error 500. It's hard to tell what's wrong with your request. Do you have a cURL working sample ? A Postman working sample? Another code (in another language) working sample?

Comment: Url is working, ı used postman and ı got response on the postman . My problem is I need send string parameters

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: " ı used postman and ı got response on the postman . My problem is I need send string parameters " Postman can generate Swift code. It can help you spot the difference, and point to your error. But currently, we can't since we don't know the API...

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting **500** as HTTP Response Code, then you need to check with the API Team, as 500 is **Server Not Available**.
If, Status Code lies in **4xx**, then you need to bother about code, For 5xx you Server /API is not responding to your request.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem **let stringRequest = ""(enUrlParams)""** this part solved my problem

```
    let url = URL(string: MemberUrl)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let parameters = "{\"Language\": \"tr\",\"ProcessType\": 1,\"Username\": \"\(self.mailTextField.text ?? "")\",\"Password\": \"\(self.passwordTextField.text ?? "")\"}"
    print(parameters)
    let enUrlParams = try! parameters.aesEncrypt(key: LoginConstants.xApiKey, iv: LoginConstants.IV)
    print(enUrlParams)
    let stringRequest = "\"\(enUrlParams)\""
    print(stringRequest)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = stringRequest.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            
        }
        if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
            self.userDC = responseString ?? ""
            self.userDC = try! self.aesDecrypt(key: LoginConstants.xApiKey, iv: LoginConstants.IV)
            print(self.userDC)
            self.login()
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```